# C# How to create a list of classes

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, loops

I am new to c#, but not to programming. First of, thank you so much for your help!

I want a class or struct whichever is appropriate which has 3 variables. A string, and two datetimes.

I want to create a loop which stores new classes in a list.

Something like:

for each item in dataViewer
create new class
assign variables
store class in list
next

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What part do you need help on? Defining a class? Instantiating the class? Creating a loop? Creating a list? It would help if you showed us what you've tried.

Comment: Amazing part of this question is that there are 5 (serious) answers

Comment: it is because everyone here rocks!

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome: For the future: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts ;)

Comment: A correction to your terminology: A class is the definition `public class Thing { ... }`, you create *instances* of your class - `Thing t = new Thing()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this easily with LINQ:

```
var list = dataViewer
    .Select(item => new YourClass
    {
        StringProperty = ...,
        DateTimeProperty1 = ...,
        DateTimeProperty2 = ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

It lets you state your intentions (create a list of `YourClass` objects from each `item` in `dataViewer`) without emphasizing the mechanics behind it (loops, etc.)

**Edit:** If you don't require a list, just a sequence, this also looks nice using the query syntax (same meaning):

```
var yourClasses =
    from item in dataViewer
    select new YourClass
    {
        StringProperty = ...,
        DateTimeProperty1 = ...,
        DateTimeProperty2 = ...
    };
```

Comment: In fact, you don't particularly need the ToList() at the end, unless you especially want it to be a List rather than just an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Mike Goodwin: Good point. I updated my answer to include the version you suggested.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe something like this

```
var list = new List<YourClass>();

foreach(var item in dataViewer) {
    var cls = new YourClass();
    // Assign variables here
    // cls.Test = item.Test;

    list.Add(cls);
}
```

Comment: so I don't even need to use pointers to accomplish this in C#? It will just know what I want to do?

Comment: Can I just say that although I had a different question, this was the answer that helped me understand my issue with creating a list of classes for outputting json. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string YourString {get; set;}
    public DateTime YourDate1 {get; set;}
    public DateTime YourDate2 {get; set;}

    public YourClass(string s, DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        YourString = s;
        YourDate1 = d1;
        YourDate2 = d2;
    }
}

public List<YourClass> Read()
{
    List<YourClass> list = new List<YourClass>();
    foreach(var item in dataViewer)
        list.Add(new YourClass(s,d1,d2)); // Read variables from item...
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Appropriate
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
IList<Appropriate> list = new List<Appropriate>();

foreach(var item in dataViewer) {
    list.Add(new Appropriate() {
        Value = item["value"],
        Start = item["start"],
        End = item["end"]
    });
}
```

---

```
IList<Appropriate> list = new List<Appropriate>();

dataViewer.ToList().ForEach(i => list.Add(new Appropriate() {
    Value = item["value"],
    Start = item["start"],
    End = item["end"]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string name, DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
    {
        Name = name;
        DT1 = dt1;
        DT2 = dt2;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DT1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime DT2 { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    public List<Foo> example(DataView dataViewer)
    {
        var foos = new List<Foo>();        

        foreach(var data in dataViewer)
        {
            foos.Add(new Foo(data.Name, data.DT1, data.DT2);
        }

        return foos;
    }
}
```